# How do I mine in the nomad?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

While driving around you often see something like, Zone Strength: RICH, but what do I actually do to find and mine minerals?  Whenever I push the button to launch a mining drone it says no minerals detected?

[image]

Comment: Guessing here, but I assume that even though the zone strength is rich, the actual minerals are all showing no values. So, I assume zone strength tells you there are minerals in the area, but you need to wait until the graphs below start showing readings until you can mine anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To harvest minerals, you’ll need to find a mining zone, which will appear on the map after activating a nearby forward station. Once you’re in the vicinity of some resources, you can use the mining computer to determine where the deposits are richest, and launch a mining drone to extract those minerals.

[image]
I often find the best places are by big piles of rocks or by 'things' that look interesting (monoliths, buildings, funky looking plants).

Drones have to be kept some distance apart, so it’s important to maximize the effectiveness of each deployment by saving them for the biggest deposits. The mining computer will tell you the general amount of resources in the zone, so you can keep mining until it’s depleted.

[Source](http://www.gamepedia.com/blogs/1440-mass-effect-andromeda-nomad-guide-controls-mining)

Comment: do the resources just automatically get added or you have to go back later to collect them?

Comment: @lI Great question, they resources are added immediately. You can see the +XXX in the lower left of your screen as soon as you deploy a mining drone.